# What is the meaning of $C'$ in $C < C′$

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I'm learning about discrete mathematics and algorithms. While reading the explanation of the definition of big $O$ notation I fount this $C<C'$, and my question is what is $C'$.

> Note that when there is one pair of witnesses to the relationship $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$, there are *infinitely many* pairs of witnesses. To see this, note that if $C$ and $k$ are one pair of witnesses, then any pair $C'$ and $k'$, where $C<C'$ and $k<k'$, is also a pair of witnesses, because $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|\le C'|g(x)|$ whenever $x>k'>k$.

Comment: Looks like $C'$ is any number larger than $C$.

Comment: Yea, $C’$ is another variable, and the condition is true for $C’$ instead of $C$ for any $C’>C.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `’` symbol is being used to mean another variable, related in purpose to a previously used variable. The character has no technical meaning, just a communication one, suggesting that $C’$ is a variable serving the same purpose as $C,$ and $k’$ serving the same purpose as $k.$

For example, if $f(x)=x+6, g(x)=x,$ then we can use $C=7,k=1,$ and get:

> If $x\geq 1$ then $$x+6\leq 7x$$

But we could also take $C’=8,k’=2.$ Then:

> If $x\geq 2$ then $$x+6\leq 8x.$$

Once we’ve found one pair $(C,k)$ to satisfy the big-O condition $f(x)=O(g(x)),$ we could pick any other pair $(C’,k’)$ with  $C’\geq C, k’\geq k$ and it will likewise satisfy the same big-O condition.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Thomas Andrews, can you please tell me where is k coming from?